# How to construct floats from bit-patterns in .NET?

Tags: .net

In need to construct System.Single values (= IEEE 754 "single precision" 32-bit floats) from their bit pattern, represented as 4 bytes (or an int32 value, big endian).

How do I do this in .NET/F#?

Comment: A better title would be "How to construct floats from bit-patterns in .NET?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn a byte array into a Single using the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class

```
byte[] data = new byte[4];
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, 0);
```

to go from an into to a byte array:

```
int i = 1234;
byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
```

(my code is in C#, but I'm sure it is easy enough for you to convert to F#)

Comment: Thanks, Mark! BitConverter.ToSingle is little-endian, so the actual F# code looks like this:

    let float_of_int32_be (x: int32) : float =
      float (System.BitConverter.ToSingle([| for k in 0..3 do yield byte (x >>> (8*k)) |], 0))

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx):

```
Assert.AreEqual(sizeof(float), sizeof(int));
int[] ints = ...
float[] result = new float[ints.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(ints, 0, result, 0, result.Length * sizeof(float));
```

The `result` array will contain the floats that are represented by the bit patterns inside the `ints` array. Each element in the `ints` array represents the bit pattern of one float.

Comment: @leppie: Exactly what the OP asks... Please be more precise with your question.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew you could use it like that  :)

Comment: @Daniel: Shouldn't that be `Buffer.BlockCopy(ints, 0, result, 0, result.Length * 4);`